# Is there a stringprep implementation for PHP?

Tags: php, string, unicode

The question is simple: Is there a Unicode stringprep implementation available for use in PHP applications?

PHP 5.3 comes with some IDN support but it can only convert between UTF-8 and Punycode. GNU libidn says something about stringprep, but there's nothing but unfinished and abandoned libidn bindings for PHP. I'm looking for a solution that either comes with PHP and is widely available or that is implemented in PHP so that I can include it in my application.

Comment: Is the PECL IDN package the one you referred to as unfinished? I have not tried it myself. http://pecl.php.net/package/idn

Comment: Now, searching the web for "php stringprep" again, 2 hours after this question, the first two hits *are* my question... The next 5 pages don't give me anything relevant. I didn't find the PECL IDN before, but I can't find out, what it is or whether it's relevant. One thing that I had found was the project from xarg.org, which I commented on below.

Answer (score 0):

PECL IDN doesn't finished or abandoned, however if you need an alternative solution

try the PHP IDNA ext: http://www.xarg.org/project/php-idna/

Comment: This doesn't have any documentation, not even a feature list. I don't want to convert Punycode, I want to use stringprep.